# Is there a way to fetch json data out of rdq files of RabbitMQ

Tags: python-3.x, rabbitmq, erlang

We had issue in our system due to which high number of ready messages were seen as a result rdq files piled up. So we took backup of `msg_store_persistent` to another place with hope to reprocess them again. Now we have huge amount of `.rdq` files in our backup(msg_store_persistent) directory.

Problem: Is there a way to parse out json data from rdq files(Over TB) and reprocess them ?

Attempt #1: I have come across [this](https://github.com/jeffbryner/rdqdump) project, tried to parse rdq files however this didn't help me much.